# How can consistent scaling of ∧, ∨, etc., be accomplished?

Tags: formatting, scaling

I've added two examples of what the expressions I wish to reproduce look like:
Here `∧` serves both as a binary operator and as the universal quantifier.  I know there are `∀` and `∃`, but I want to reproduce what is in the book.

[image]

In this image ∨ serves as the existential quantifier.

[image]

This is what Mathematica produces when I input the same expressions into an equation cell:

[image]

The same kind of thing happens with the set theoretical connectives `⋃` and `⋂`, etc. It makes sense for some operator symbols to scale. For example, summation and integral symbols.  But for these operators, I want to control their appearance with a minimal number of keyboard or mouse actions. What I really want are upper case and lower case variants of these symbols which act in the same way as do letters and numerals regarding spanning.

Is there a way to accomplish something like this without impacting the behavior of other symbols that automatically scale? As it stands, the scaling of these symbols in complex expressions is arbitrary and inconsistent.  Exactly the same expression will often be scaled differently depending on the order in which it is typed.

I also want the formatting to persist when saving as PDF.

```
Cell[BoxData[
 FormBox[
  RowBox[{
   UnderscriptBox["\[Or]", "p"], 
   UnderscriptBox["\[Or]", "q"], 
   RowBox[{"(", 
    RowBox[{"2", "\[InvisibleComma]", 
     RowBox[{
      SuperscriptBox["q", "2"], "=", 
      RowBox[{
       SuperscriptBox["p", "2"], "\[And]", 
       RowBox[{"\[Not]", 
        RowBox[{"(", 
         RowBox[{
          RowBox[{
           UnderscriptBox["\[Or]", "s"], 
           RowBox[{"2", "s"}]}], "=", 
          RowBox[{
           RowBox[{
            RowBox[{"p", "\[And]"}], 
            UnderscriptBox["\[Or]", "s"], 
            RowBox[{"2", "s"}]}], "=", "q"}]}], ")"}]}]}]}]}], ")"}]}], TraditionalForm]], "Equation",
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.755520330280187*^9, 3.755520443924959*^9}, {3.757609467459089*^9, 3.757609620292385*^9}}]
```

Comment: Have you looked into [`ScriptLevel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScriptLevel.html)?